# Remove identical values if the same as previous in a time series

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, subset

I have a time series:

```
 df <- data.frame(t=1:10, x= c(5,7,8,9,5,5,5,5,4,3))
```

I want to remove values that are identical to the previous value to obtain:

```
 x = c(5,7,8,9,5,4,3)
```

I tried:

```
 df[unique(df$x),]
```

But this gives the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 filter(x != lag(x, default = first(x)-1))

   t x
1  1 5
2  2 7
3  3 8
4  4 9
5  5 5
6  9 4
7 10 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df[c(1, diff(df$x)) != 0, ] 

   t x
1  1 5
2  2 7
3  3 8
4  4 9
5  5 5
6  9 4
7 10 3
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can use `head` and `tail`

```
subset(df, c(TRUE, head(x, -1) != tail(x, -1)))

#    t x
#1   1 5
#2   2 7
#3   3 8
#4   4 9
#5   5 5
#9   9 4
#10 10 3
```

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang there are supposed to be. Read the question again.

Comment: Although there are supposed to be 2 5's in the output but answer needed some adjustments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Another `base` solution would be using `rle`.*

If you want to subset the dataframe based on the criteria, you can use `lengths`. Otherwise, if you only need the subset of `x` column, we should extract the values from `rle`. See below;

```r
df[cumsum(rle(df$x)$lengths), ] # dataframe subset

#     t x
# 1   1 5
# 2   2 7
# 3   3 8
# 4   4 9
# 8   8 5
# 9   9 4
# 10 10 3
```

```
rle(df$x)$values # vector of values

# [1] 5 7 8 9 5 4 3
```

---

---

*Or using `data.table`:*

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df_large)[, rn :=1:.N, by = rleid(x)][rn == 1, .(t, x)]

 #     t x
 # 1:  1 5
 # 2:  2 7
 # 3:  3 8
 # 4:  4 9
 # 5:  5 5
 # 6:  9 4
 # 7: 10 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)    

df <- data.frame(t=1:10, x= c(5,7,8,9,5,5,5,5,4,3))

subsetVec <- df$x - lag(df$x) != 0
subsetVec <- replace_na(subsetVec, TRUE)
df[subsetVec,]
```